# Jquery loop through li to calculate height

Tags: jquery, loops, sum

I have three divs that contains li. I want to color in red the li that exceed a certain height.  Within first ul I want to calculate height of the first li, see if it's exceeding 100, if not add it to the height of second li, compare, if it exceeds 100 I color this in red. Then within the second ul I do same operation but since it's another ul, result must be at 0. So I tried this:

```
var result = 0;

$('li').each(function(){

       result += $(this).height(); 
  alert(result);

    if(result > 100){
$(this).css("color", "red");
    }

 });
```

But it seemed to not reinitialize the count when changing the ul. So it colors at 4th till the end. But what I want is to color only the 4th li because only him make the height exceed inside a ul. I tried to loop through ul but it did something weird..

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ybonmbgt/31/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Then iterate all `ul` first and reset the counter before iterating over `li` under `this ul`

```js
$('ul').each(function() {
  var result = 0;
  $(this).find("li").each(function() {
    result += $(this).height();
    if (result > 100) {
      $(this).css("color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>how are you ? </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    <li> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. </li>
    <li> Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</li>
  </ul>

</div>


<div class="list">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</li>
    <li> Ut enim ad minim veniam </li>
    <li> Excepteur</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ybonmbgt/33/)

Comment: thanks! I think I exactly tried this but maybe I did a little mistake.. but now it's working thanks a lot!